# Retrieving manually set request attribute from RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes

Tags: spring, httprequest

In my Servlet Filter code I am setting one attribute in HttpServletRequest object:

```
request.setAttribute("testname", "name");
```

I know, using *RequestContextHolder* we can retrieve the attributes from the request which comes directly from the browser. But Can we retrieve the above attribute which I have manually set in the request, using RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes:

```
RequestAttributes cr = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
if (null != cr) {
 cr.getAttribute("testname",RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your question.

```
RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
request.getAttribute("testname");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can retrieve any manually set attributes by using **RequestContextHolder**.
If you set an attribute like `request.setAttribute("testname", "name")` somewhere, you can retrieve it using **RequestContextHolder** using the following code:-

```
RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().getAttribute("testname", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final HttpServletRequest currentRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    String ProjectContext = currentRequest.getContextPath();
```

Happened to visit this page for some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
/**
 * Obtain current request through {@link RequestContextHolder}.
 */
protected static HttpServletRequest getCurrentRequest() {
  RequestAttributes attrs = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
  Assert.state(attrs instanceof ServletRequestAttributes, "No current ServletRequestAttributes");
  return ((ServletRequestAttributes) attrs).getRequest();
}
```

https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes/getRequest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).